# How can I get back into the output of a .sh script which is running in the background?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I am running ubuntu server on another machine on my network.

I have a script running in the background using nohup.
`nohup ./start.sh`

This out the output of that script in a txt file.  I want to be able to enter that task again and run other other commands like `/backup` or `/stop`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How would you "run other other commands like `/backup` or `/stop`" if `start.sh` was in the foreground?

Comment: Its kind of like running python in a terminal.  I don't know how else to describe it.

Comment: Do you mean that normally `start.sh` displays a prompt where you can interactively enter `/backup` or `/stop` and the tool will react?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly that.